# NMinimize fails on Mesh?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, mesh, finite-element-method

### Context

*I want to identify the minimum of a solution of a PDE found on a mesh.*

### Problem

I do not understand why [`NMinimize`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/NMinimize.html) fails on a mesh?

As a test case, consider:

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"] 
disk = ToElementMesh[Disk[]]
```

so that

```
disk["Wireframe"]
```

produces this beautiful image :-)

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Now turning to the numerical optimization problem, this fails

```
NMinimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ disk]
```

whereas this works

```
 NMinimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y}  ∈  Disk[]]
```

### Questions

> Could anybody reproduce this?
>
> Why does NMinimize fail?
>
> Any idea of a workaround?

I am using mathematica 10.2 on OSX.

Comment: Try converting the element mesh to a region: `NMinimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] MeshRegion[disk]]`.

Comment: @ilian thanks  that works: please turn your comment into an answer

Comment: @ilian I tried that just out of curiosity and I get:
NMinimize::elemc: "Unable to resolve the domain or region membership condition {x,y}\[Element]"

Comment: @leosenko Perhaps your version is older than 10.0.2.

Comment: @ilian unfortunately so, 10.0.1

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As of version 10.2, `NMinimize` does not work with `ElementMesh` (which is not `RegionQ`) directly. Perhaps it could, but for now I would suggest converting the element mesh to a region:

```
NMinimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} \[Element] MeshRegion[disk]]
```

The above will work in *Mathematica* 10.0.2 and later.

**Update**

In version 10.3, `ElementMesh` can be used directly in `NMinimize`

```
Needs["NDSolve`FEM`"]
NMinimize[x^2 + y^2, {x, y} ∈ ToElementMesh[Disk[]]]
```